# How change subsection format?

Tags: fonts

I want that a subsection was 12pt, no bold, italic and times new roman. How can I do it ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! See the documentation of `titlesec`.

Comment: In addition to Bernards comment, it also depends on which document class you're using. Some provide their own interface to change things like this.

Comment: I use a report.

Comment: What's the main document font size? 10pt, 11pt, 12pt, or something else? Is Times (new) Roman the main document font?

Comment: The main document fon size is 12pt, and use Times new roman

Comment: so you are using lualatex or xelatex on windows presumably? (Times New Roman isn't easily available to pdftex or on linex)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply copy the definition from `report.cls` and change the font in `\subsection` to normalsize (12pt) italic, and use fontspec to put the document in Times New Roman.

You need lualatex or xelatex on Windows to access Times New Roman in this way (I used cygwin texlive here).

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
                                     {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                     {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
%                                     {\normalfont\large\bfseries}}
                                     {\normalfont\itshape}}

\makeatother
\begin{document}

\section{Something}
\subsection{italic 12 pt subsection}
Some text.
\end{document}
```